# R function write.xlsx only convert 1 data

Tags: r

I have 4 columns and 34 rows of data. I tried to export it into excel with xlsx format using `write.xlsx`. But when I convert it, the excel file only shows 1 data.

```
library(openxlsx)
data = scale(DATA2)
write.xlsx(data, "outpu2t.xlsx");
```

This is my data

[image]

and this is the output

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. So, you can provide some of your data with `dput(head(DATA2))`, then edit your question and provide the data there. I made a quick example, but am not able to reproduce the issue. Is there any other steps that you applied to `DATA2`?

Comment: Even when i tried with only 4 data,  it still only shows 1. maybe its something wrong with my R studio?

Comment: Are you using Excel to open the output or other software?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `str(data)`? I'd guess you have a class issue or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key consideration here is that the output of the `scale()` function is an object of type `matrix()` when `write.xlsx()` requires an input of type `data.frame()`. The following code creates a data frame, uses `scale()` to scale it, and prints the structure to show that the data frame has bene converted to a `matrix()`.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(4 * 34),ncol=4))
str(df)

> df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(4 * 34),ncol=4))
> str(df)
'data.frame':   34 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X1: num  0.438 0.134 0.671 0.392 0.613 ...
 $ X2: num  0.9 0.793 0.668 0.351 0.275 ...
 $ X3: num  0.201 0.892 0.74 0.788 0.14 ...
 $ X4: num  0.996 0.619 0.492 0.904 0.615 ...

scaledData <- scale(df)
str(scaledData)

> scaledData <- scale(df)
> str(scaledData)
 num [1:34, 1:4] -0.174 -1.386 0.752 -0.36 0.521 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4"
 - attr(*, "scaled:center")= Named num [1:4] 0.482 0.591 0.508 0.471
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4"
 - attr(*, "scaled:scale")= Named num [1:4] 0.251 0.206 0.306 0.29
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4"
```

We can solve the problem by casting the output of `scale()` with `data.frame()`.

The following code generates a 4 x 34 matrix, scales it, and casts to a `data.frame()` as part of `write.xlsx()`.

```
aMatrix <- matrix(runif(4 * 34),ncol=4)
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(data.frame(scale(aMatrix)),"./data/aSpreadsheet.xlsx")
```

The resulting spreadsheet looks like this when viewed in Microsoft Excel.

[image]

Note that `writexl::write_xlsx()` will also fail when passed an input of type `matrix()`, so this is not a `tidyverse` vs. `openxlsx` problem.

```
b <- scale(aMatrix)
write_xlsx(b,"./data/aSpreadsheetWritexl.xlsx")
```

...generates the following error:

```
> write_xlsx(b,"./data/aSpreadsheetWritexl.xlsx")
Error in write_xlsx(b, "./data/aSpreadsheetWritexl.xlsx") : 
  Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
```

Comment: DATA <- read_excel(file)
DATA1= DATA[2:5]
DATA2= data.frame(DATA1)
STANDARISASI = scale(DATA2)
write.xlsx(STANDARISASI, "outpu2t.xlsx");

This was my previous code and it didn't work

then I change it based on your solution
Thank you, sir, your solutions work for me

Answer (score 0):

I am cognisant that you asked this question pointing to the package `{openxlsx}`. I used this a while back as well and ran into multiple problems. Being biased and leaning towards the `{tidyverse}` family, there is a cool package that comes from that part of the R/RStudio ecosystem: `{writexl}`.

If not yet installed: install.packages("writexl")

Then run the following without pain ... and it does not require to install other fancy stuff/dependencies/etc:

```
library(writexl)

# create a reproducible data set of 34 rows
my_data <- iris[1:34,]

# write-out my_data to the data subfolder in the project - configure as appropriate for your environment
write_xlsx(x = my_data, path = "./data/my_data.xlsx")
```

This gets you without problems:

[image]

Comment: Hello Ray. As I noted in my answer,`write_xlsx()` fails if you pass it an object of type `matrix()`, so changing packages from `openxlsx` to `writexl` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Len, coerce the matrix to a data.frame/tibble and you are good.

Comment: That's exactly my point. Given the problem posed in the original post, one needs to cast the `matrix()` object to `data.frame()` (or `tibble()` as you proposed in your comment) after using `scale()` and before using `write_xlsx()` in order for `write_xlsx()` to process without error. Therefore, the problem posed by the original poster isn't a tidyverse vs. openxlsx issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert matrix `data` into a data frame.

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

Then,

```
write.xlsx(data, "outpu2t.xlsx")
```

will work as expected